# How to put a text BESIDE a photo, while the photo's position is at the center?

Tags: php, html

As simple as the title says.

PHOTO CODE :

```
<center> <a href="home.php" title="logo"><img src="images/header.jpg" width="860" height="250" alt="logo"> </img> </a> </center>
```

TEXT CODE :

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) && ($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_PASSWORD']))
{

    echo "Welcome "."<b>".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."</b>". " ";
    echo '<a href="logout.php" title="Logout"><b>Logout</b></a>';
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use table

```
<tr>
<td>Image</td><td>text</td>
</tr>
```

or use div

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
image
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block">
text
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly, the CSS code doesn't work as I wanted it to work. The photo refuses to be in the center. I also forgot to say that I want the text to be at the top. It always keep at the bottom. Anyways, The table method worked perfectly but I had to use an empty <td> to help me put the photo in the center by giving it a big width. It doesn't look professional, but thanks after all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Basic css box model.

Div Container - align ceenter.
Image - Text
Close div.

You technically don't need anything else unless some of your CSS is overwriting something it shouldnt.

Of you are having trouble you can do 2 things.

Div subcontinent - width:#px;margin:auto;

Or
Image - display:inline-block;

Storing a password in a session is both against PCI compliance and a major security risk btw. Risky even if stored md5 encrypted.

Comment: About the password, I didn't know that I'm still a beginner. Any good advice regarding security? Thanks btw.

Comment: Yes, only request the password once upon log in. Basic logic: create account stores an md5 encrypted password in the database. 2 upon log in, check the data of the post, converter the password to md5, compare it to the data stored in a database already encrypted to MD5. If it matches up, you know the user is good to go, so memorize his ID into the session.  At that point, it's safer to use the Id  to pull data from the database rather then storing everything into a session variable. However there is nothing wrong with storing names...

Comment: Well, thanks again but as I told you, I'm a beginner. I know nothing about encryption. But security is nice I guess.

Comment: Php had a nice built in function md5() that will encrypt the data for you. Your best bet would be to find a good tutorial to understand and learn by example.

Comment: Aren't there sites that decrypts MD5 codes? Wouldn't that be useless ?

Comment: To really decode (decrypt is not the right word) md5 you need to have a key. Otherwise it can take a regular pc years to brute force all permutations of a 6 letter password.  Also since you are storing it encrypted you are forced to develop a proper password reset procedure.  When you only compare the password once during log in, you reduce the chances of anyone being able to retrieve it.